# can not refresh oracle materialized iew

Tags: oracle, dbeaver

I created the following materialized view in oracle

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW APC_SCHEDULED_STOP_CNT_VW
AS
(
  SELECT /*+ NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION */ 
    SD.SERVICE_DATE AS APC_SAMPLE_DATE,
    SSSD.VERSION_ID ,
    SSSD.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID,
    SSSD.TIME_PERIOD_ID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT(SCHEDULED_STOP_ID)) AS SCHEDULED_STOP_CNT
 FROM "RHOMBUS_PRODUCTION"."ZZ_JANET_TEST_SSSD"  SSSD,
      "RHOMBUS_PRODUCTION"."SERVICE_DATES" SD
 WHERE 1=1 
   AND SSSD.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID  = SD.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID
GROUP BY SD.SERVICE_DATE, SSSD.VERSION_ID, SSSD.SCHEDULE_TYPE_ID, SSSD.TIME_PERIOD_ID 
)
```

I am trying to refresh it in dbeaver as follows

```
EXECUTE  dbms_mview.refresh('APC_SCHEDULED_STOP_CNT_VW')
```

I get the following error  Any suggestions on why it is not working?  I thought i had it working once last night

```
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Comment: The error is ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement.  I have edited the question

Comment: Does DBeaver support the SQL\*Plus `execute` shorthand for an anonymous block? And if so does it matter [how you execute it](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SQL-Execution) - as a statement or as a script?

Comment: With DBeaver should use `BEGIN dbms_view.refresh(); END;`

Comment: That appears to have worked.  Thanks

Comment: You can also use `call`, [apparently](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/749).